# Firebase query not returning correct data

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data in Firebase:

```
- Info/
  -2018-09-23-13-38-00-WhyNewYo
  -2018-09-23-14-04-57-PompeoWe
  -2018-09-23-14-10-32-FocusonE
  -2018-09-23-14-39-00-SenPatty
  -2018-09-23-14-40-30-Rebelatt
  -2018-09-23-14-57-33-Piratesa
```

Each entries are created at a different time but I named them based on a specific title so I know which is the latest and it would be in alphabetical order when I view them in the Firebase console automatically.

When I wanted to query the latest 2 data (the last 2 based on the order shown above), but Firebase seems to return incorrect data and I am using the following code:

```
FIRDatabaseReference *dataRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
dataRef = [dataRef child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/info"]];
[[[dataRef queryOrderedByValue] queryLimitedToLast:2] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    NSDictionary *infoFromFirebase= snapshot.value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query and observe `FIRDataEventTypeValue`, you get all matching nodes in a single snapshot. If you call `snapshot.value` the data is converted to a dictionary, and information on the order of the matching nodes is lost.

To maintain the order of the nodes, be sure to iterate over the children of the `snapshot`  with `for (FIRDataSnapshot* child in snapshot.children) { … }`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have accepted this as the answer the query.